# java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Failed resolution of: Landroidx/work/R when updating Gradle Android Plugin

Tags: android, gradle, android-gradle-plugin

I started updating dependencies for an older project of mine, but then noticed that the app does not start after some dep updates - it thows a `java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Failed resolution of: Landroidx/work/R$bool` exception. This might happen because on startup I reschedule a Worker to do some periodic IO.

I narrowed it down to the `com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.5.1` -> `com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.6.1` change in `build.gradle` and this does correspond [with the docs](https://developer.android.com/studio/releases/gradle-plugin#simplified-r-class) but that does not help much.

A bit more context about the current set up where the problem occurs:

- I use the old classpath and version for the work library with `implementation "android.arch.work:work-runtime-ktx:1.0.1"`
- I tried reproducing this set up in a test project with no success, which might indicate that this is some kind of cache problem. I tried removing them with `rm -rf ~/.gradle/caches` but that did not help
- [Android Studio also displays this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Crtdi.png) problem in the `WorkManagerImpl.java` file (from the work library source) which would indicate that this indeed is not a gradle cache issue

EDIT 1: I tried removing the `androidx:work` package uses and the this exception is thrown by another support library from the `androidx` group. This points me to there being some there being some other funky class processing going on.

EDIT 2: I've found the solution, and this would apply to any `android.support` libraries - a gradle plugin `realm-android` was messing up the build, so updating it seems to have fixed the problem. Similar problems might occur with other code-generating plugins.

Any tips on how to approach this would be appreciated

Comment: I deleted my Gradle build cache and cleaned the project to fix it. Very concerning.

Comment: I get the same error on AS 4.0 with gradle 4.0.0 and 4.0.1 (and WorkManager 2.4.0), but cleaning the caches doesn't solve the problem, unfortunately.

Comment: I had to break it down by creating a new project and transfering all dependencies but I found the bad guy. It was `apply plugin: 'io.objectbox'` in my build.gradle file. Seems to be a bug there.

Comment: `rm -rf ~/.gradle/caches` fixed it for me

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As the OP sayed, it could be any other plugin or dependency as well. In my case, the error came from the ObjectBox plugin.

Updating ObjectBox from 2.5 to 2.6 solved the issue for me.

```
objectboxVersion = '2.6.0'
```

However, I needed to add the following lines to my build.gradle for ObjectBox to work again.

```
    kotlinOptions {
        jvmTarget = JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
    }
```